# I can't access my site admin dashboard via wp-admin

Tags: email-verification, wordpress-login, wordpress-admin

You know how all these websites send out links to their new users for them to verify their Email address? I'm setup user verification process through email address , I will send email verification link to user email onclick on link user will be verified.

but the problem is that i am setting up usermeta field when user login the function will check user if it verified or not if verified it will be login otherwise show error when i was login to admin it will not access me to admin dashboard.

```
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'check_user_activation_status', 10, 2);
function check_user_activation_status($user) {
    if( ! $user->has_cap('administrator') ) {
        if ( get_user_meta($user->ID ,'wp_user_level',true) != 10 ) {
            if( get_user_meta($user->ID, 'activated', true) == 'true' ) {
                return $user;
             }
        } else {
            return $user;
        } 
    }

    return new WP_Error('Account Not Active...');
}
```

and also it will not showing error text
[login page look like after login failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2c2v.jpg)

sorry for bad english...

Answer (score 0):

This hook passes two parameters, $user and $password (plaintext). In order to generate an error on login, you will need to return a new WP_Error() object.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_authenticate_user

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Check User Status.
 *
 * @param $user WP_User Object
 */
function check_status( WP_User $user ) {
 
    $status = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'user_status' );
 
    if ( 1 !== (int) $status ) {
        $message = esc_html__( 'User not verified.', 'text-domain');
        return new WP_Error( 'user_not_verified', $message );
   }
 
    return $user;
}
 
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'check_status' );
```